# Push object to a JSON file subarray/object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js

#### Both JS or Node.js solution are welcome

I have a json file with following structure (I have remove some unnecessary part)

```
{
  "post": {
    "sample_post": {
      "slug": "/sample"
    }
  }
}
```

And I want to push a new object array like `"sample_post"` and someone suggest to change this array to

```
{
  "post": [{
    "sample_post": {
      "slug": "/sample"
    }
  }]
}
```

to use push but I got error like `data.push` is not a function since I use jquery to get the external json I don't know if this cause error

Comment: Have you deserialized the JSON into an actual JS object (with array syntax), or are you trying to push onto the JSON itself?

Comment: It seems to be `data.post.push` instead

Comment: @Scott I would like to add object to json file this is kind of post/content database

Answer (score 1):

based on your code :

```
var data = {
  "post": {
    "sample_post": {
      "slug": "/sample"
    }
  }
}
```

you have to use a temporary variable to store the new array :

```
var _tmp = []
_tmp.push(data.post)
```

and overright your initial data

```
data.post = _tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

I m not sure what you want is just :

```
var test = {
  "post": {
    "sample_post": {
      "slug": "/sample"
    }
  }
};

test.post = [test.post];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prepare object like shown below,

```
var obj = {
  "post": [{
    "sample_post": {
      "slug": "/sample"
    }
  }]
}
```

then you should be adding the objects into "post" array, in either of the ways.

```
obj.post.push({"key": "value"})
```

or

```
obj["post"].push({"key": "value"})
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer but it's not quite match the case I want, just imagine that the array is the array for all the settings, blog post data. so even I store the data right in the js file I still need to save the changes just think today I push some value to "post" object but next time I open it again it will become the original one not the one I modify it, so I want to save the array after I push it. Can you get what I mean?

Answer (score 0):

To use push function, the object should be of type Array. But in your case its a json object. So you first need to make it Array either by initializing it by blank array. ie data.post = [] or directly with array with required elements. After this you can use push in post.push().
Hope this help!

Comment: So is there any way to save json array to a local array